# Throttling Limit for Liquid Transform Connector Azure Logic Apps

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps, throttling

While using liquid connector, I faced Error 429 with no message. It generally suggest that the throttling issue which happens when number of request increases to connector. However, I don't find any documentation mentioning the same over here as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/

Can any one tell what is the threshold/throttling limit of liquid connectors.?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not clear about the threshold/throttling limit of liquid connectors, I went through the document of liquid connector but can't find the throttling limit.

But for your problem, I think you request the connector too frequently. If you use the connector in a "**For each**" loop, I think you can control its frequency by click the `...` button and click "**Settings**". Then turn on "**Concurrency Control**" and set "**Degree of Parallelism**" as `1`. Then it will request liquid one by one in for each loop.

[image]

[image]